# Setting custom theme with AppBaseTheme parent

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, titlebar

I defined this theme in my **styles.xml:**

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> 
   <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
</style>
```

In that custom theme I define a custom title bar. Apart from the custom title bar I want to keep the theme original:

```
parent="AppBaseTheme"
```

The problem is that when I try to set this custom title like this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

I get an error on the second line which says:

> You cannot combine custom titles with other title features.

How can I keep the original theme with only changing the title to my `custom_title_bar` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call

```
setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, ...)
```

where ActionBar has already been set (e. g. with Holo theme), than it can cause this problem.

Try this:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

in your custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Customize your title bar in style of custom theme